# Se muestra doble los roles y los permisos - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, autenticación

Estoy haciendo un menú, pero quiero limitarlo a que solo algunos usuarios con un permiso determinado lo puedan ver.

La consulta:

```
SELECT idpermiso FROM permisos_usuario WHERE idusuario = "user001"
```

Resultado:

```
idpemiso
 PER001
 PER002
 PER003
```

Código:

```
while($sqlRow=$sqlPermisos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  if ($sqlRow['idpermiso'] == 'PER001' || $sqlRow['idpermiso'] == 'PER002')
       {
        echo "muestra menu ";
    }
}
```

Pero el resultado que me aparece son dos veces:

> `muestra menú` `muestra menú`

Pero solo debería mostrarme uno, haciendo solo una comparación si tiene tal permiso, lo muestra, de lo contrario no muestra nada.

Comment: user001 tienes dos de estos en la tabla

Comment: te esta mostrando dos por que al devolver esos datos el compara con lo que tienes en el if y al tener un while el itera esos 3 resultados compara el primero como es igual muestra menu compara segundo es igual muestra menu y como el tercero no esta no muestra menu

Comment: `SELECT idpermiso FROM permisos_usuario WHERE idusuario = "user001" AND idpermiso=" PER001" `

Comment: **user001 tienes dos de estos en la tabla** - Sí, es una tabla para almacenar los permisos, es decir, en la tabla **permisos_usuario** están todos los permisos que tiene el usuario como por ejemplo: **PER001 = Crear, PER002 = Editar** y así con todos los demás usuarios, por eso al realizar la siguiente consulta `SELECT idpermiso FROM permisos_usuario WHERE idusuario = "user001"` me muestra este resultado: **idpemiso = PER001,PER002,PER003** es decir que el usuario 001 tiene 3 permisos.

Comment: **SELECT idpermiso FROM permisos_usuario WHERE idusuario = "user001" AND idpermiso=" PER001"** también habia pensado esto, pero no me resultó porque lo limito solo al **PER001** , a lo que quiero llegar es que el usuario puede tener muchos permisos para diferente items en el menú, como ver, editar, crear, eliminar, cada uno es un permiso, y cada item (menú usuario, menu libros, menú historicos) es otro permiso.

Comment: pues yo te recomendaria que crearas otro campo donde almacenes el valor de false o true para deshabilitar esos menus

Comment: asi como esta puede funcionar pero te tocaria crear otro metodo para modificas el validar para cambiar el estado a false o true que equivale a mostrar y no mostrar

Comment: Hola. Sólo te hace falta **interrumpir el ciclo de validación** de permisos **al encontrar una coincidencia favorable**. Escribe `break;` inmediatamente después de invocar *"mostrar el menú"*

Answer (score 0):

El problema surge porque tienes dos permisos para el usuario y al iterar por todos los resultados de la consulta pasará por la validación dos veces.

Para solucionarlo debes romper la iteración del ciclo al encontrar la primera coincidencia con la sentencia `break`, de la siguiente forma:

```
while($sqlRow=$sqlPermisos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  if ($sqlRow['idpermiso'] == 'PER001' || $sqlRow['idpermiso'] == 'PER002'){
        echo "muestra menu ";
        break;
  }
}
```